# Why is a summable family at most countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Why is a summable family at most countable ?
>
> Let $(a_i)_{n\in I}$($a_i\in [0,\infty],\forall i$) is summable then, $\{i\in I:a_i≠0\}$ is at most countable.
>
> a family is said to be summable if $\sum_{i\in I}a_i<\infty$

Can we always choose a countable set s.t., every member of this set is bigger then some $\epsilon$, but how ?

Comment: There is a positive integer $N$ so that infinitely many $a_n$ exceed $1/N$ or infinitely many are less than $-1/N$.

Comment: @David Mitra $a_i$'s are non-negative, otherwise i don't think it is possible.

Comment: @derivative: it is possible.  The question is what the symbol $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ means.

Comment: @Martin Argerami is this not clear ?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you think it is? How do you define it?

Comment: @Martin Argerami just sum of all $a_i$'s

Comment: That is not even true for series over a countable set. The sum of infinitely many numbers is not defined per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any positive $\varepsilon$ denote by $I_\varepsilon$ the set of all indices for which $a_i$ is greater than $\varepsilon$: $I_\varepsilon=\{i \in I \mid a_i > \varepsilon\}$.

Now it boils down to two things:

1. $I_\varepsilon$ is finite for every $\varepsilon > 0$. This is the part where it is necessary to use that the sum $\sum_{i \in I} a_i$ is finite.
2. Realize that your set $\{i \in I \mid a_i > 0\}$ can be represented as a union:
   $$
       \{i \in I \mid a_i > 0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_{1/n}
   $$
   Any union of a countable family of finite sets is at most countable, qed.

*PS:* There was no definition given for the sum $\sum_{i \in I}a_i$ in the question. But, since all $a_i$ are nonnegative, I just assumed that you mean $\sum_{i \in I}a_i = \sup_J \sum_{j \in J} a_j$, where $J$ iterates over all finite subsets of $I$.

Comment: Yes that's the definiton, but does it change anything ?

Comment: Change compared to what? I find it hard to imagine any other definition for an infinite sum of nonnegative numbers that is essentially different. But the actual execution of step 1 in the plan above does depend on the precise definition that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\{i :\ a_i\ne0\}=\bigcup_n\{i: \ |a_i|> 1/n\}.
$$

If  the set on the left is uncountable,  then at least one set on the right is infinite.

Now, when considering a series indexed by a net, one has an issue with the definition.  The usual way to define the symbol $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ is by taking the limit along the net of finite subsets of $I$, ordered by inclusion. This implies that absolute convergence is required.

In the case above,  if $|a_i|>1/n$ for infinitely many $i$, then $\sum_i|a_i|=\infty$, and so the series cannot be convergent.