# Support for functions in $\ell^1(I)$ is always countable?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, function-spaces

For an arbitrary set $I$, not necessarily countable, is the space $\ell^1(I)$ consist of functions on $I$ whose support is always countable? Here "support" doesn't refer to the closure, but only those elements in $i\in I$ such that $f(i)\neq 0$, where $f\in \ell^1(I)$.

This is because, for an uncountable set $I$, the norm
$$\|f\|_1:=\sup_{F\in \mathcal{F}}\left\{\sum_{j\in F} |f(i_j)|\right\}< +\infty,$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the set/family of all finite subsets of $I$, forces fucntion $f$ only takes nonzero values on at most countably many points $i_j\in I$.

Is that correct? I know $\ell^1(I)$ is equivalent to $L^1(I)$ through the counting measure.

Comment: Yes, if $f:I\to \mathbb R$ has uncountable support, then for some $n$ there are uncountably many values $i\in I$ such that $|f(i)>\frac1n.$ Then show that $f\notin \ell^1(I).$

Comment: Basically, the set of values $\{i\in I\mid |f(i)|>1/n\}$ must be finite for each $n.$ or $f\notin\ell^1.$ And the support is then the (countable) union of these finite sets.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the link. Yes it's connected. I just try to confirm functions in $\ell^1(I)$ are like that.

Comment: It was much more than connected. What was still missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $f\in \ell^1(I)$, then $f$ has countable support. Indeed, note that

$$\{i \in I: f(i)\ne 0\}= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{i\in I: |f(i)|> n^{-1}\}.$$
The set $\{i \in I: |f(i)| > n^{-1}\}$ is finite for every $n$, otherwise you could pick an infinite subset $I_0$ with the property that $|f(i)| > n^{-1}$ for all $i\in I_0$ and then
$$\|f\|_1=\sum_{i \in I}|f(i)|\ge \sum_{i \in I_0}|f(i)| \ge \sum_{i \in I_0} n^{-1}=\infty.$$
Hence, the support of $f$ is a countable union of finite sets, and thus a countable set.

Comment: This is exactly the answer contained in the [proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724573)